# Why do I have to alter the source code of firebase-functions-test in order to send the path of my private key?

Tags: javascript, firebase, testing, google-cloud-functions

The source code in index.js has this:

```
const lodash_1 = require("lodash");
const lifecycle_1 = require("./lifecycle");
module.exports = (firebaseConfig) => {
    const test = new lifecycle_1.FirebaseFunctionsTest();
    test.init(firebaseConfig);
    // Ensure other files get loaded after init function, since they load `firebase-functions`
    // which will issue warning if process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG is not yet 
    set.
    let features = require('./features').features;
    features = lodash_1.merge({}, features, {
        cleanup: () => test.cleanup,
    });
    return features;
};
```

Now, I'm unable to get my test to work unless I alter it slightly by letting the path go through like this:

```
const lodash_1 = require("lodash");
const lifecycle_1 = require("./lifecycle");
module.exports = (firebaseConfig, path) => {
    const test = new lifecycle_1.FirebaseFunctionsTest();
    test.init(firebaseConfig, path);
    // Ensure other files get loaded after init function, since they load `firebase-functions`
    // which will issue warning if process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG is not yet 
    set.
    let features = require('./features').features;
    features = lodash_1.merge({}, features, {
        cleanup: () => test.cleanup,
    });
    return features;
};
```

I don't think this is a bug with firebase-functions-test, because I had it working earlier, but it suddenly stopped working. This is the code I have in my test:

```
const test = require('firebase-functions-test')(config, './functions/test/devKey.json');
```

Am I doing this properly?

Comment: Looks like you found a bug.  The team is working on it.  Thanks for writing this up.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks. I would have sent it in as a bug, but I thought it might have been my own mistake.

Comment: Hi @JoeHidakatsu, I just posted Doug's comment as a community wiki answer. As I can see the issue was clarified, please accept the answer

Comment: [Federico Panunzio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9551346/federico-panunzio) wrote an answer (now deleted) that stated: *"Looks like you found a bug. The team is working on it. Thanks for writing this up."*

Comment: @FedericoPanunzio Sorry, I'm a bit new to posting in stack overflow. What should I do?